# Primes occurring as orders of elements of a finitely presented group

Tags: gr.group-theory, co.combinatorics

Is it true that given a finitely presented group $G$, either all primes
or only finitely many of them occur as orders of elements of $G$?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

No.  The set of primes can be whatever you want (added: within reason!  As Benjamin Steinberg points out, it can in fact be any *recursively enumerable* set of primes).

First, note that for infinitely presented groups, the torsion can be whatever you like: the torsion in the group

$*_i \mathbb{Z}/p_i$

is precisely the set of primes $p_i$, by standard facts about free products.  (Added: As long as the set of $p_i$ is recursively enumerable, then this group admits a recursive presentation on a countable set of generators.)

By Higman's Embedding Theorem, the above group can be embedded in a finitely presented group.  More subtlely, this embedding doesn't introduce any new torsion---see, for instance, Theorem 2.5 of [this preprint of Chiodo](http://arxiv.org/abs/1107.1489).

**Clarification:** Higman's Embedding Theorem is commonly stated as only applying to finitely generated countable groups.  In fact, an old construction of Higman, Neumann and Neumann shows how to embed a countably generated group into a 2-generated group; if the countably generated group is recursively presented, then the 2-generated group can be taken to be recursively presented as well.

**Further update:**  Following Benjamin Steinberg's <strike>comments below</strike> answer and an argument in [another paper of Chiodo](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet/search/publdoc.html?arg3=2011&co4=AND&co5=AND&co6=AND&co7=AND&dr=pubyear&pg4=AUCN&pg5=TI&pg6=PC&pg7=ALLF&pg8=ET&review_format=html&s4=chiodo&s5=&s6=&s7=&s8=All&vfpref=html&yearRangeFirst=&yearRangeSecond=&yrop=eq&r=2&mx-pid=2774658) (see also Francois G. Dorais's comments), I think we have a *very exciting* characterization of the sets of primes that can occur as torsion in finitely presented groups.  (For the solvable-word-problem case, one also needs a theorem of Clapham, which says that the Higman Embedding can be made to preserve solvability of the word problem.)

**Very exciting theorem:**

Let $P$ be a set of primes.

1. $P$ occurs as the torsion in some finitely presented group if and only if $P$ is $\Sigma^0_2$.
2. $P$ occurs as the torsion in some finitely presented group with solvable word problem if and only if $P$ is recursively enumerable.

Comment: Well -- but is the free product of infinitely many cyclic groups of prime order finitely generated? -- As I understand, Higman's 
Embedding Theorem is only for finitely generated groups, or am I missing something?


Comment: In any case, for reasons of cardinality, the set of primes cannot be "whatever one wants" -- there are uncountably many sets of primes, but only countably many finitely presented groups. 

Comment: You need the set of primes to be recursive for this to work. In this case the free product is recursively presented which is enough for Higman. 

Comment: Look in the section of D Cohen's book on Higman embeddings to see that a recursive presentation is enough (the generators don't need to be finite). 

Comment: Sorry, Benjamin is quite right - the set of primes does indeed need to be recursive.

Comment: Huh, there's a sort-of interesting problem here (for a rather, er, specialised definition of interesting), isn't there?  It's not clear to me that it's *necessary* that the set of primes occurring be recursive.  (It will be recursive whenever the word problem is solvable, but of course the word problem may not be solvable.)  So what sets of primes can be realised, beyond the recursive sets?

Comment: Ugh, as Benjamin points out again, I mean re, not recursive: the fact that a recursive presentation is really a recursively enumerable presentation is a source of never-ending confusion to me.

Comment: You are right that you need the word problem decidable to guarantee that the orders be re. 

Comment: You can enumerate words w with $w^p=1$ for some prime but you cannot figure out if $w\neq 1$. So basically it seems to me you are looking at the intersection of an re and a co-re set, or something like that. 

Comment: The paper of Chiodo seems to show that any co-re set can also be the orders of elements of a finitely presented group. See Thm 2.7. 

Comment: @HW: Thank you very much! -- Now with your clarification regarding 
Higman's Embedding Theorem and the restriction to recursively
enumerable sets of primes, it's clear.


Comment: Yes, Chiodo's argument shows that you can do any intersection of any re set and any co-re set of primes.  (If {p_i| i in S} is the co-re set, just add relations x_i=1 for all i not in S.)  And, as Benjamin observes, the set of primes is always of that form.

Comment: It seems that this works. What a nice question. 

Comment: Well what is clear is that the set of all pairs (w,p) with order of w equal to p is the intersection of an re and co-re set. Now we take a computable projection to get the primes.  I assume this is still in re intersect co-re. 

Comment: @HW and Benjamin: I originally thought about asking which sets of primes can occur, but then preferred to ask a question that would 
more likely admit a definite answer -- and now you have answered even
more than the former question. -- Great!!

Comment: I added a clarification in an answer below because I don't see how to prove a computable image of a difference of re sets is again a difference of re sets. 

Comment: The answer to http://mathoverflow.net/questions/121268/computable-images-of-differences-of-r-e-sets seems to say we get those subsets of primes living in the $\Sigma^0_2$ part of the arithmetic hierarchy. 

Comment: Yes, I think the $\Sigma^0_2$ sets of primes are precisely the ones that can be achieved this way. The statement itself is $\Sigma^0_2$ and we can mimic a $\Sigma^0_2$-statement $\exits m \forall n \phi(p,m,n)$ as follows. For each $p$, keep track of a potential $m$ starting with $0$ and a word $w$ with the relation $w^p = 1$. As soon as you find an $n$ such that $\phi(p,m,n)$ is false, add the relation $w = 1$ then increment $m$ and pick a fresh word $w$ with the relation $w^p = 1$. (Continued...)

Comment: (...) If $\exists m \forall n \phi(p,m,n)$ is true then we eventually stabilize at some $m$ and the word $w$ we picked for this $m$ has order $p$. Otherwise, all the potential $w$'s we picked eventually become $1$. The words $w$ have to be chosen in such a way that they don't interfere with each other much so that we don't accidentally add an element of order $p$ while working for other primes.

Comment: (...) Assuming such non-interfering $w$'s can be chosen, this gives a recursively presented group with the required properties. Then, as I understand from the answer, this group can be embedded into a finitely presented group without additional torsion.

Comment: Francois. That is essentially my answer. 

Comment: Yes, I realized on Friday evening that we didn't quite have the correct statement, but haven't had time to .  Well done Benjamin and Francois for sorting it out!

Answer (score 10):

**Notation:**

If $n\in \mathbb{N}$, then we denote by $\pi(n)$ the set of all non-trivial factors of $n$, including $n$ but excluding $1$. Call a set $X \subseteq \mathbb{N}$ *factor-complete* if it is closed under taking non-trivial factors. That is, $n\in X   \Rightarrow  \pi(n) \subseteq X$. 
Now we can state a strengthened answer to the main question of this post:

**Complete characterisation:**

Let $X\subseteq \mathbb{N}$. Then the following are equivalent:

$1$. $X$ is the set of orders of torsion elements of a finitely presented group $G$.

$2$. $X$ is factor-complete and has a $\Sigma_{2}^{0}$ description.

That $1\Rightarrow 2$ is immediate; torsion-orders are closed under taking factors, and have a $\Sigma_{2}^{0}$ description (see the proof of theorem 3.5 in arXiv:1107.1489v2). That $2 \Rightarrow 1$ can be seen from the following result, which is proved by a generalisation of an argument provided by Francois Dorais in an earlier post on this thread:

**Technical result:**

There is a uniform algorithm that, on input of a computable function $\phi: \mathbb{N}^3 \to \mathbb{N}$ which describes a factor-complete $\Sigma_{2}^{0}$ set $A$, outputs a finite presentation $P_{\phi}$ such that $A$ is precisely the set of torsion elements of $gp(P_{\phi})$.

As any set of primes is factor-complete, we get the following corollary.

**Answer to main question:**

A set of primes $A$ appears as the torsion elements of a finitely presented group if and only if $A$ has a $\Sigma_{2}^{0}$ description.

Observe that if $X\subseteq \mathbb{N}$ then the set $X_{prime}:=\{p_{i}\ |\ i \in X\}$ is factor-complete and one-one equivalent to $X$ (being a set of primes, with a computable numbering). So we conclude with the following:

**Sets which can be realised up to one-one equivalence:**

Given any $\Sigma_{2}^{0}$ set $A$, the set $A_{prime}$ is one-one equivalent to $A$, and can be realised as the set of orders of torsion elements of some finitely presented group $G$.

For completeness, we provide the proof of the technical result. This is the construction described by Francois Dorais, generalised and applied carefully so that none of the torsion elements `bump in to each other'. Apologies for its lenght.

**Proof of technical result:**

Let $\{a \in \mathbb{N}\ | \ (\exists m)(\forall n) (\phi(a,m,n)=1)\}$ be the description for the factor-complete $\Sigma_{2}^{0}$ set $A$, where $\phi: \mathbb{N}^3 \to \mathbb{N}$ is our computable function. 
Let $p_{1}, p_{2}, \ldots$ be the standard indexing of the primes ordered by size. 
Then we construct a countably generated recursive presentation as follows:
Take the infinite set of symbols $x_{1}, x_{2}, \ldots$; this is our generating set.
For any fixed $i>1$, add the relation $x_{p_{i}}^{i}=1$. Then, start successively computing $\phi(i,1,1), \phi(i,1,2), \phi(i,1,3), \ldots$ increasing the last variable by $1$ each time. If at some point $\phi(i,1,n)\neq 1$ then stop, add the relations $x_{p_{i}}=1$, $x_{p_{i}^{2}}^{i}=1$, and start successively computing $\phi(i,2,1), \phi(i,2,2), \phi(i,2,3), \ldots$. If again some $\phi(i,2,n)\neq 1$, then stop, add the relations $x_{p_{i}^{2}}=1$, $x_{p_{i}^{3}}^{i}=1$, and start computing $\phi(i,3,1),\phi(i,3,2), \ldots$. By interleaving this process for all $i \in \mathbb{N}$, we get a countably generated recursive presentation which we denote by $Q_{\phi}$. Notice that:

a) If $i \in A$, then there will be some (smallest) $m$ such that $\phi(i,m,1)=1, \phi(i,m,2)=1, \ldots$, and so the relation $x_{p_{i}^{m}}^{i}=1$ will be present, but no other relation involving $x_{p_{i}^{m}}$, and so $\langle x_{p_{i}^{m}} \rangle \cong C_{i}$ becomes a free product factor in this group.

b) If $i \notin A$ then for all $m \in \mathbb{N}$ we will have the relation $x_{p_{i}^{m}}=1$, and since $A$ is factor-complete $i$ does not divide any element of $A$. Hence no element of order $i$ occurs in the group.

So we end up with the group  $ gp(Q_{\phi}) \cong F_{\infty}$ $* _ {a \in A}  ( * _ {j \in \pi(a)}  C_{j})$

(With a slightly more complicated indexing, one could do away with the $F_{\infty}$ factor). As $A$ is factor-complete, we immediately see that it is the set of orders of torsion elements of $gp(Q_{\phi})$. Now apply the construction of Higman-Neumann-Neumann, and then the construction of Higman, to embed this in a finitely presented group with presentation $P_{\phi}$. Note that these embeddings strictly preserve the set of orders of torsion elements (see lemma 6.9 and theorem 6.10 of M. Chiodo `Finding non-trivial elements and splittings in groups'). Also note that this construction is completely uniform in the computable function $\phi$ used to describe the set $A$.

Comment: Wow, still a more general result ... -- Great! -- Thanks!

Comment: Minor remark: on this site, for some reasons set brackets need to be
escaped by two backslashes -- otherwise they vanish.

Comment: No problem. I really should have realised this when I was working on arXiv:1107.1489v2. Full credit to Francois for the very useful construction in computability theory. Did you have a particular application of this question in mind when you asked it?

Comment: Ah, damn. My bad. First time posting to MO. I thought I had sorted out all the formatting issues.

Comment: Further minor remarks: 1. I think "$1 \Rightarrow 2" and
"$2 \Rightarrow 1" at the beginning of your post need
to be interchanged(?) 2. "factors" should rather mean "divisors", right?


Comment: Arrows were indeed wrong, thanks. Factors and divisors mean the same thing (I believe). Thank you for checking through so thoroughly!

Comment: I posted this question since I wondered how rich the class of 
finitely presented groups is in a certain sense. I would have found
finitely presented groups rather boring if the answer to my
question would have been "yes". --
But now the answers tell me that the class of finitely presented
groups is richer than I thought!


Comment: Another formatting issue: the expression $F_{\infty}*{a \in A}(*{j \in \pi(a)}C_{j})$ does not seem to compile.

Comment: In the comment it does compile -- strange.

Comment: @Stefan: Encoding arbitrary $\Sigma_{2}^{0}$ or $\Pi_{2}^{0}$ sets into a single finitely presented group, which I first did in arXiv:1107.1489v2, shows that such groups (even individually) are incredibly rich. When considered collectively, they are even richer: A result by Boone-Rogers shows that the set of finite presentations of groups with solvable word problem is $\Sigma_{3}^{0}$-complete. I have yet to see (but am interested in seeing) if any set harder than $\Sigma_{2}^{0}$ or $\Pi_{2}^{0}$ can be encoded into a single finitely presented group.

Comment: That formatting issue is baffling me, and I have no way of fixing it at the moment (first time on M.O.).

Comment: Figured it out (spacing around the _ ). Fixed it.

Comment: @Maurice: I wonder to what extent these nice results can be turned
into practical algorithms. Thus for example for which sets $X$ of 
integers it would be computationally feasible to obtain a finite 
presentation of a group which has precisely the $n \in X$ as orders
of torsion elements. Also it would be interesting to see how long
the resulting presentations would be in concrete nontrivial examples.


Comment: @Stefan: The problem here is that you are not given the ($\Sigma_{2}^{0}$) set $A$, but a description involving just the function $\phi$. It is possible to come up with very complicated descriptions of very `easy' sets (recognising descriptions of the empty set is undecidable, so these can get very hard!). Since there are infinitely many distinct $\Sigma_{2}^{0}$ sets, such presentations would be unbounded in `length' (the presentations I describe above can all be made to be 2-generator, so we can define length as the sum of the lengths of the generators).

Comment: Additionally, chasing Turing Machines has been done in the past, with some success. Valiev has constructed explicit examples of universal finitely presented groups. I would be interested in seeing the following:

1. An explicit finite presentation of a universal finitely presented torsion-free group.

2. An explicit finite presentation of a group whose set of orders of torsion elements form a $\Sigma_{2}^{0}$-complete set.

Perhaps an analysis of the work of Valiev would be of some use, but I can't say for sure.

Comment: @Maurice: Interesting! -- Anyway I'd be interested to see some 
concrete examples. To start with something (supposedly!) easy,
would it be feasible to find a finite presentation for a group
whose orders of torsion elements are precisely the primes
congruent to 1 mod 4? -- Knowing that something exists is
one important thing, but explicitly finding it is still more
(in particular for someone like me with a background in explicit 
computation!).


Comment: MC, could you briefly point to where in arXiv:1107.1489v2 you encode arbitrary $\Sigma^0_2$ sets into groups?  Are you referring to your Theorem 5.8?

Comment: @HW @ Stefan: My apologies. I have indeed claimed something in my comment which is not true (though the discussion that follows still holds). The comment should instead begin as follows:

Encoding a $\Pi_{2}^{0}$-complete set into a single finitely presented group, which I first did in arXiv:1107.1489v2 (theorem 5.8), shows that........

So no, I did not encode arbitrary $\Sigma_{2}^{0}$ or $\Pi_{2}^{0}$ sets into a single finitely presented group. But I have a $\Pi_{2}^{0}$-complete set encoded into a single finitely presented group, so can reduce all $\Pi_{2}^{0}$ sets to it.
(tbc....)

Comment: (...continued) Lempp realised a $\Sigma_{2}^{0}$-complete set in the set of all finitely presented groups, but that was at the group level. Similarly, Boone-Rogers realised a $\Sigma_{2}^{0}$-complete set in the set of all finitely presented groups. The set K from theorem 3.6 of arXiv:1107.1489v2 , if shown to be $\Sigma_{3}^{0}$-complete, would be another interesting encoding.


Comment: @Stefan: Regarding your question "Would it be feasible to find a finite presentation for a group whose orders of torsion elements are precisely the primes congruent to 1 mod 4?" This is a recursive set of primes, but the task of finding a finite presentation with this set of torsion orders is still quite difficult. An even easier task: a finite presentation whose torsion orders is precisely all primes. Sounds easy, but it is not. I recommend looking at Valiev (arXiv:1107.1489v2 citations [25], [26]). These are short papers. In [26] he constructs a 14-generator 21-relator universal fp group.

Comment: @Maurice: Precisely all primes may be difficult, I don't know. But there is a nice example of a group having all primes (and in fact all positive integers) as orders of torsion elements, namely the Higman-Thompson group (which happens to be a simple group), see Higman, G., Finitely Presented Infinite Simple Groups, Department of Pure Mathematics, Australian National University, Canberra, Notes on Pure Mathematics (1974). That group even admits explicit computation.


Comment: @Stefan: Of course, Higman's universal finitely presented group also has this property (though the presentation is likely to be a little more complicated). I think the real challenge here is to find the "best" Turing machine to encode the set you care about, and then directly apply Higman's construction. As I commented earlier, this is mostly about chasing Turing machines, which can get complicated. Valiev came up with one presentation, and then improved it (4 years later).

I'll take a look at the Higman reference next week when I have library access.

Comment: @Maurice: I find Higman's simple group particularly nice since it admits the explicit determination of a permutation representation which is suitable for computation (see the first example in http://www.gap-system.org/DevelopersPages/StefanKohl/rcwa/doc/chap7.html).

Comment: Stefan - sure, but a group encoding all natural numbers is necessarily much easier than any other, since the Turing machine recognising the set of natural numbers is necessarily very easy.  A set which is even slightly algorithmically non-trivial, such as the set of primes, is likely to be much harder.

Answer (score 8):

This should be a comment to HW's answer but it is too long.  I believe that the correct theorem is that a collection P of primes is the set of prime orders of the finite order elements of a finitely presented group iff there is an re set U, a computable function $f\colon U\to Primes$ and r.e. sets L,K contained in U such that $P=f(L-K)$. I don't know if such a set of primes must be a difference of r.e. sets (which is HW's) answer.

Here is the proof. Suppose first that we have a finitely presented group. Then U will be all pairs (u,p) where u is a word over the generators and their inverses and p is a prime, f is the projection to the second coordinate, L is all pairs (u,p) with $u^p=1$ in the group (r.e. by finiteness of the presentation) and K is all pairs (u,p) with u=1 (r.e. for the same reason). Clearly the prime orders of elements of the group is f(L-K).

Conversely, given U,L,K,f as above consider the group G with generators U subject to the relations $x^{f(x)}=1$ for x in L and $x=1$ for x in K. This group has an r.e. set of generators and an r.e. set of relators and hence by the argument of HW can be embedded in a finitely presented group with the same finite orders. Now G is a free product of infinite cyclic groups (one for each element of U not in K or L) and finite cyclic groups of order from f(L-K) (there may be repetitions because f is many to one).

**Edit.** I have learned from [Computable images of differences of r.e. sets](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/121268/computable-images-of-differences-of-r-e-sets/121274#121274) that the sets of the above form are precisely the $\Sigma^0_2$ sets of the arithmetic hierarchy and hence much broader than differences of re sets. In his comments to HW's answer François sketches how to construct the analogue of G above directly from a logical formula.

Comment: I think in the last paragraph the generators of $G$ are meant to be
the projections of the elements of $U$ to the first coordinate, and
similarly the $x$ in the basis in $x^{f(x)} = 1$ should rather be its
projection to the first coordinate -- or am I mistaken?
Otherwise -- as far as I can tell!! -- this looks right to me.
-- Thanks again!


Comment: Last paragraph U is any re set not just the pairs in the second paragraph. 

Comment: No, this should definitely be a separate answer, and deserves full credit.  This is really a great example of how interesting decision theory arises from innocuous group-theoretic questions.

Comment: @HW, this question ended up being one of the most fun experiences I had on MO. It shows that by putting together several mathematicians who may never have met in person with differing areas of expertise one can pose and solve a nice problem. 

Comment: Hear, hear, Benjamin.