# Computable images of differences of r.e. sets

Tags: lo.logic, computability-theory

Suppose f is a computable function from a recursively enumerable set U to the natural numbers and that L,K are r.e. subsets of U. Is f(L-K) a difference of r.e. subsets? The motivation comes from

[Primes occurring as orders of elements of a finitely presented group](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/121178/primes-occurring-as-orders-of-elements-of-a-finitely-presented-group)

A positive answer would mean that the theorem proposed in HW's nice answer is 100% correct. Otherwise the $\epsilon$-clarification in my answer is actually needed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is f injective?  If so, yes.  If not, no.  In the second case, you could achieve any $\Sigma^0_2$ set.

Comment: It is not injective. Are the sets I am talking about always $\Sigma_2^0$?

Comment: Don't you need $f$ to be infinite-to-one everywhere to get every $\Sigma^0_2$-set in this way?

Comment: I am thinking of f,U,L,K as things I can vary and I would like to know the full range of primes that can be picked up. 

Comment: That is sets of primes 

Comment: Benjamin, $\Sigma^0_2$-sets are the sets which are r.e. relative to the halting set, this is much larger than the differences of r.e. sets.

Comment: @Francois: I think you're right. If we insist $f$ be finite-to-one, then it seems that $X\in\Delta^0_2\impliesf(X)\in\Delta^0_2$, by the limit lemma: let $X_s$ be the approximation to $X$ at stage $s$, and approximate $f(X)$ by saying that $n\in f(X)_s$ if there is at stage $s$ some $y$ which appears to be in $X$ such that $f(y)=n$. Then for each $n$ and each $y\in f^{-1}(n)$, cofinitely often we have $y\in X_s\iff y\in X$; since $f^{-1}(n)$ is finite, we then get that cofinitely often, $n\in f(X)_s\iff n\in f(X)$, so $f(X)$ is $\Delta^0_2$.

Comment: (In the above, technically in defining $f(X)_s$ I need to restrict attention to $y<s$ as possible witnesses to keep the approximation effective, but that doesn't wind up affecting anything.)

Comment: @Francois, but I am allowing any computable image of a difference of re sets. 